# Fluid mechanics and statics

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

I wanted to ask if I can use this law $P=\rho gh$
to compare between the pressure of two solid irregular cylinders (they don't have the same area above and at the bottom) but they do have the same area at the bottom
And also if I can use it to compare the pressure of one same liquid in two irregular cylinders (don't have the same area above and at bottom) and they don't have the same area at the bottom. And if no then why should the area be equal at the bottom when talking about comparison between liquids or fluids?

Comment: What even are irregular cylinders? I think you had better add some pictures.

Answer (score 3):

The equation $P=\rho gh+P_s$, where $P_s$ is the pressure at the surface, works for all imaginable shapes of containers.

Liquids and fluids are not different from each other. In physics fluids mean the umbrella term for both liquids and gasses, while liquids are specifically liquids. In everyday life liquids and fluids mean the same thing.

Comment: I am talkin about if I can use this law with the irregular solids not liquids or fluids. I can understand what you said. Thank you